# End Stamement not working in SAS

Tags: sas

can you only use END Stamement in SAS in set statement? For example...why isn't this working?

```
filename FS '/folders/myfolders/list4.txt';
data steward;
infile FS dlm = ',' END = EOF;
input Name $ Age Gender $;
if EOF = 1;
run;
```

Comment: What makes you think it is NOT working?

Comment: I'm not getting any values returned. I tried another file, same format (column delimited, same number of observations) and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most SAS data steps actually stop when the `INPUT` or `SET` statement reads past the end of the file.

I suspect that your input file is either empty or does not have enough data to satisfy your INPUT statement.

Comment: Looks ok, but normally you would want to add the `DSD` option in the `INFILE` statement so that SAS will treat two commas as an indication of a missing value and handle quoted values properly.  You also should add the `TRUNCOVER` option to prevent SAS from hunting to the next line if their are not enough values for all of the variables on the current line.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check EOF  or  IF as the data step will terminate automatically once it reaches the last record.

Solution:

```
DATA WORK.input1;
    LENGTH
        name             $ 5
        age                8
        gender           $ 1 ;
    FORMAT
        name             $CHAR5.
        age              BEST2.
        gender           $CHAR1. ;
    INFORMAT
        name             $CHAR5.
        age              BEST2.
        gender           $CHAR1. ;
    INFILE 'E:\saswork\Input.txt'
        LRECL=256
        FIRSTOBS=2 /*I am skipping first row, as it containts column names*/
        ENCODING="WLATIN1"
        DLM='2c'x /* this is "," delimiter; I am using windows*/
        MISSOVER
        DSD ;
    INPUT
        name             : $CHAR5.
        age              : ?? BEST2.
        gender           : $CHAR1. ;
    put _all_; 
RUN;
/*Contents of the Input.txt*/
/*name, age, gender*/
/*jack,32,M*/
/*John,45,M*/
/*Sally,38,F*/
```

Output:

```
name=jack age=32 gender=M _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
name=John age=45 gender=M _ERROR_=0 _N_=2
name=Sally age=38 gender=F _ERROR_=0 _N_=3
```